# .NET 7 : problem authenticating minimal Web API with Bearer

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I am creating a Minimal Web API using .NET 7 and bearer tokens, but when I login, it creates the key successfully, but when I type bearer token and the key, it said that I have logged in successfully but I get a http 401 "Not Authorised" error. Any idea how to fix it?

This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace WebApiAuth
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Name = "Authorisation",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "JWT authernication for Minimal Api"
            };

            var securityReq = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type  = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        }                       
                    },
                    new string[] { }
                }
            };

            var contactInfo = new OpenApiContact()
            {
                Name = "Nickpsal",
                Email = "nickpsal@gmail.com",
                Url = new Uri("https://www.datatex.gr")
            };

            var license = new OpenApiLicense()
            {
                Name = "Free"
            };

            var info = new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Version = "V1.0",
                Title = "Minimal Api with Jwt Auth",
                Description = "Minimal Api with Jwt Auth",
                Contact = contactInfo, 
                License = license
            };

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]!)),
                    ValidateLifetime = false, // in any other app this needs to be true
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
                };
            });

            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", info);
                options.AddSecurityDefinition("Beaver", securityScheme);
                options.AddSecurityRequirement(securityReq);
            });

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            var summaries = new[]
            {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
            };

            app.MapPost("login", (User user) =>
            {
                if (user.Username == "nickpsal@gmail.com" && user.Password == "nick123")
                {
                    var SecureKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]!);
                    var issuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
                    var Audience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
                    var SecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(SecureKey);
                    var Credentials = new SigningCredentials(SecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                    var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                    {
                        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new []
                        {
                            new Claim("Id", "1"),
                            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Username),
                            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Username),
                            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                        }),
                        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                        Audience = Audience,
                        Issuer = issuer,
                        SigningCredentials = Credentials
                    };
                    var token = jwtTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                    return Results.Ok(jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(token));
                }
                return Results.Unauthorized();
            }).AllowAnonymous();

            app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", (HttpContext httpContext) =>
            {
                var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
                    new WeatherForecast
                    {
                        Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                        Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
                    })
                    .ToArray();
                return forecast;
            })
            .WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
            .WithOpenApi().RequireAuthorization();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

I try changing the Security algorithm to HmacSha256 but still get the same error. I verified the key successfully to the site, but I still have the same problem. I tried with Swagger and Postman - same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a change on the code i put first the Authentication

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Now it works fine on Postman but the problem on Swager reamains

Answer (score 0):

In builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen in the options.AddSecurityDefinition("Beaver", securityScheme) you specified "Beaver" instead of "Bearer".